# flutter: Widgets are rebuilding even though `provider` is used

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I am using `provider` for flutter state management. Below is my code

**Home**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          //backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 72, 100, 10),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(25, 72, 114, 10),
          title: Text("something"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.white70,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                fontSize: 16.0,
                letterSpacing: 0.15),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "Fresh Products",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Frozen Products",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Home()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Home build methof");
    return TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(context, listen: false)
                .getAllSpecies(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        Container(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Loading Data... Please Wait",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text("An error Occured"),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Consumer<ProductSpeciesImpl>(
                      builder: (context, data, child) => GridView.builder(
                          physics:
                              ScrollPhysics(), // to disable GridView's scrolling
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(context)
                              .productList
                              .length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  childAspectRatio:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                          .5 /
                                          190),
                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                //print("sdsdsdsd");
                                // print(snapshot.data[index].name + " " + snapshot.data[index].idProductSpecies.toString() + " "+ snapshot.data[index].photo);
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/products",
                                    arguments: {
                                      "name": Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(
                                              context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .productList[index]
                                          .name,
                                      "id": Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(
                                              context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .productList[index]
                                          .idProductSpecies,
                                      "photo": Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(
                                              context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .productList[index]
                                          .photo
                                    });
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 4.0,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(context,
                                                listen: false)
                                            .productList[index]
                                            .name,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }));
                }
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
```

**ProductSpeciesImpl**

```
class ProductSpeciesImpl
    with ChangeNotifier
    implements ProductSpeciesInterface {
  NavLinks navLinks = NavLinks();

  List<ProductSpecies> productList = [];

  @override
  Future<void> getAllSpecies() async {
    var data = await http.get(navLinks.getAllProductSpecies());
    var jsonData = convert.json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    try {
      productList = jsonData
          .map<ProductSpecies>((json) => new ProductSpecies.fromJson(json))
          .toList();

      print("Product sIZE: " + productList.length.toString());

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

The code works fine. The issue is every time I visit another page and come back to this page, the UI gets reloaded. I have used `consumer`, as far as I understood, `consumer` will only load the relevant part when it is called. That means I don't have to run my product loading code inside `init` as well.  So, I do not understand why this is happening.

Appreciate your support to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initiating an HTTP request in your `build()` function here by calling `getAllSpecies()`. You are not supposed to do that.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: Provider.of<ProductSpeciesImpl>(context, listen: false)
                .getAllSpecies(),
```

`build()` functions are supposed to have no side effects. Please convert the widget to `StatefulWidget` and do your loading in `initState()`. Alternatively, make a parent `StatefulWidget` do the loading in its `initState()` and hand the data to this widget in its constructor.

Comment: Thank you. Why I used that way is, In a reputed tutorial, he was loading in builder using `futurebuilder` and amazingly nothing did reloaded! Can you help me understand this please, the `consumer` and `provider` are incapable of stopping the rebuilding process when the page get reloaded?

Comment: If you just return the existing data in you `Provider` when `getAllSpecies()` is called that would be better. In general, you should be fine with many `build()` calls, your code should not depend on whether `build()` was called or not.

Comment: Alright. So I am going to get the data from server during the `initState` and load these "existing" data to the `ListView` using a `consumer`. hope thats good?

Comment: errrr.. I converted to stateful, and noticed my `initstate` also runs whenever you navigate away from the screen and navigate back. Actuallly, I am on tabs, navigating from tab to tab,

Comment: I guess you can do `if (productList != null) loadProductList()` in your provider class but that's not a nice approach. Your `ProductSpeciesImpl` is always loading and not ever using the `productList`. If I were you I would scrap this and use https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html Do not try to tie HTTP loading to widget events. Your tab can be built many times, you should be explicit about when you will do the HTTP request. Which could possibly be in the initState of the widget that contains the tabs. Sorry for the misleading upvote earlier.

Comment: Thank you. Well I loaded items in the `initstate` and used the `consumer` to get the already loaded items into widgets. The shared link seems the same I am doing, using `ChangeNotifier`